# Помогите разобраться с yield

Tags: ruby

Здравствуйте, я не так давно начал изучать Ruby и у меня возникли трудности с итератором yield. Если можно, объясните на пальцах, пожалуйста, как это работает. Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Что именно не понятно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yield` - это управляющая конструкция, с помощью которой передается управление блоку. Вместе с управлением могут передаваться параметры.
Пример:

```
def my_method
  # ... такая-то логика
  yield('yep') if block_given?
  # ... такая-то логика
end

my_method { |txt| p txt } # Выведет "yep"
```

`yield`, в переводе с английского - "уступать дорогу".

Вот пример использования блока:

```
new_array = [[1, 5], [3, 3], [2, 2]].sort{ |x, y| x[1] <=> y[1] }
p new_array # выведет [[2, 2], [3, 3], [1, 5]]
```

Здесь сортировка происходит по возрастанию 2-го элемента.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А зачем он используется? Не удобнее ли это всё сделать в методе, без yield?

Comment: @basania блоки - одна из очень удобных "фишек" Ruby. Метод `my_method` может быть определен в любом месте. И вместо того, чтобы править исходный код метода проще ему передать блок, который он выполнит, передав в него свои внутренние переменные. Как пример - пользовательская сортировка массива. Проще передать в неё блок, который будет принимать 2 значения и хитро сравнивать их, а сам метод, на основании возвращаемого `yield` значения будет располагать эти элементы, чем каждый раз писать сортировку с нуля под себя.

Comment: Кажется понял, но смутно. Если не трудно, можно пример с сортировкой массива?

Comment: @basania привел пример с пользовательской сортировкой. Для таких вещей и используются блоки.

Comment: Всё понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

В функциональном программировании обычное дело передавать в одну ф-цию другую ф-ции. Первая ф-ция будет по необходимости вызывать вторую ф-цию -- чаще всего с передачей параметров. В некоторых языках это называют "коллбэком".

Например, мы хотим описать ф-цию, которая распечатывает из массива числа, прибавляя к ним 10, но проделывает это только с теми числами, какие удовлетворяют условию, которое передадим следом за массивом.

```
def select_and_add_10 array, condition
  array.each do |element|
    p element + 10 if condition.call element
  end
end
```

Здесь `condition` -- переменная, через которую передаем лямбду в пользование ф-цией `select_and_add_10` вот так:

```
select_and_add_10 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], lambda{ |element|
  2 < element && element < 6
}
```

> 13
>   14
>   15

Но чтобы не писать `lambda`, в Ruby есть синтаксический сахар, называемый блоками (`do end`) -- недостаток заключается в том, что лямбд можно передать сколь угодно много, т.к. это просто аргументы функции, а блок передается только один.

```
def select_and_add_10 array, &condition
  array.each do |element|
    p element + 10 if condition.call element
  end
end

select_and_add_10 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] do |element|
  2 < element && element < 6
end
```

И `yield` -- это еще один синтаксический сахар, позволяющий не именовать блок, ведь он всего один и потому не нуждается в идентификаторе.

```
def select_and_add_10 array
  array.each do |element|
    p element + 10 if yield element
  end
end

select_and_add_10([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) do |element|
  2 < element && element < 6
end
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, только я с лямбдами/проками очень плохо знаком